# Is the function $1/x$ bijective on $[0, \infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions, rational-functions

It is well-known that the function $f (x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is not bijective on the domain of non-negative real numbers (that is, $[0, \infty)$.) , since $f( \cdot)$ may not be well-defined at zero point.

> I am curious that what if we admit the convention that $0^{-1} = \infty$ and $\infty^{-1} = 0$.
>
> Then, under this setting, is $f(x)$ bijective on $[0, \infty]$ now?

*Could anyone help me out please? Thank you very much in advance!*

Comment: Whether $\infty$ is a symbol or a number, it's still an element of your set $[0,\infty]$. The function $f:[0,\infty]\to [0,\infty]$ is bijective because no two elements of the set map to the same element, and every element of the set is mapped to by some element.

Comment: Thank you so much @gj255 . I got it now :)

Comment: "*as far as I know, $\infty$ is just a symbol rather than a number.*"  It is no more or less of a number than $\sqrt{2}, i,$ or $j$ are.  True, $\infty$ is not a *real number* as in an element of $\Bbb R$, nor is it a complex number or a quaternion, etc... but it *is* an "*extended real number*" or "*extended complex number*" etc...  Anything could be a "number" in the proper context, including infinity.  It just so happens that in *most* contexts it is not, but that is not to say that there aren't *some* contexts where it is, the scenario you describe being one of them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your explanations. I learned it :) and really appreciate it

Comment: @Paradiesvogel: Be aware of the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) and the [projective real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line). Pretty much every notion of "infinity" you've seen in calculus and analysis can be better understood as referring to the corresponding point of the extended real line rather than as "just a symbol", and many of the remaining cases refer to the projective real line.

Comment: ... In my opinion, I think "infinity is just a symbol" is a rather harmful piece of advice to students -- it directly gets in the way of gaining a deeper understanding of what's going on in calculus. The only good I can see in it is that it may help prevent mistakes from confused students who are tempted to treat $\infty$ as if it behaved like an ordinary real number.

Comment: We could, as far as the rules of what you are allowed to do define $\frac 1{pinkhonkhonk} = Babar$ and $\frac 1{Babar}=Tantor$ and $\frac 1{Tantor} = pinkhonkhonk$ as say $f:(0,\infty)\cup\{pinkhonkhonk,pinkhonkhonk,Tantor, Babar\}\to(0,\infty)\cup\{pinkhonkhonk,pinkhonkhonk,Tantor, Babar\}$ via $f(x)=\frac 1x$ and that is a bijection.  So defining the *extended reals* =$\Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ is certainly acceptable.  Just don't assume it *means* anything more than it does or behaves as the reals do.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you so much for your kind advice. I totally agree with you, since my math teacher just taught me like this, so that I was quite confused about the notion of infinity until now.

Comment: Thanks for your exposition @fleablood . I learn it. :)

Comment: On the Riemann/Complex sphere (the standard geometric model for the Alexandroff one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$) the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is an isometry (distance preserving bijection).

Also @fleablood appears to have jokes, invoking cartoons about elephants that talk and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you define $f(0)=\infty$ and $f(\infty )=0$, then your function

$$ f(x)=1/x \text { if $x\in(0,\infty)$ }$$   along with   $f(0)=\infty$ and $f(\infty )=0$ will be  bijective on $[0,\infty]$

It will map $(0, \infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$ and maps the endpoints to the endpoints.